# How to solve error when trying to implement hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm wanting to create a hook to place the states and event functions of my menus. But when I import the click function in this component, the following error appears:

"No overhead matches this call.
The 1 of 2 overload, '(props: { slot?: string | undefined; style?: CSSProperties | undefined; title?: string | undefined; ref?: ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject< ...> | null | undefined; ... 251 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...> | undefined; } & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<. ..>', generated the following error.
The type 'boolean | (() => void)' cannot be assigned to type 'MouseEventHandler | Undefined'.
Type 'boolean' cannot be assigned to type 'MouseEventHandler'."

How can I solve it?

```
  import { useState } from "react";


export const useMenu = () => {
    const [openCardOptions, setOpenCardOptions] = useState(false);

    const handleOpenCardOptions = () => {
      setOpenCardOptions(!openCardOptions);
    };

    return [openCardOptions, handleOpenCardOptions]
}
```

```
import { useMenu } from "../../hooks/useMenu";


export const NoteCard = () => {
  const [openCardOptions, handleOpenCardOptions] = useMenu()

  return (
    <Container>
      <TopBar>
        <ImgContainer>
          <img src={noteImg} alt="Note" />
        </ImgContainer>

        <Menu onClick={handleOpenCardOptions}>
          <img src={menuImg} alt="Menu" />

          {openCardOptions && (
            <CardOptions>
              <div>
                <img src={viewImg} alt="View" />
                <p>Visualizar</p>
              </div>

              <div>
                <img src={pencilImg} alt="Pencil" />
                <p>Editar</p>
              </div>

              <div>
                <img src={binImg} alt="Bin" />
                <p>Deletar</p>
              </div>
            </CardOptions>
          )}
        </Menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the return statement of your function to

```
return [openCardOptions, handleOpenCardOptions] as const;
```

If you check the existing return type of `useMenu()`, you'll see it returns `Array<boolean | (() => void)>`--a variable array where every item can either be a boolean or a function. That's not what you're looking for though.

You instead want your return type to be a tuple, where the first item is always a boolean and the second item is always a function. `as const` tells TypeScript to treat array literals as tuples instead of arrays (among other things, [noted here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)).

You could also explicitly write out the return type for useMenu if that makes more sense:

```
export const useMenu = (): [boolean, () => void] => {
```